# How to count the number of entries in a csv file using pyspark streaming

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, bigdata, spark-streaming, rdd

I have a monitor directory contains number of `.csv` file. I need to count the `number of entries` in each in coming `.csv` file. I want to do this in pyspark streaming context.
This is what I did,

```
my_DStream = ssc.textFileStream(monitor_Dir)
test = my_DStream.flatMap(process_file)  # process_file function simply process my file. e.g line.split(";")
print(len(test.collect()))
```

This does not give me the result that I want. For e.g `file1.csv` contains `10` entries, `file2.csv` contains `18` entries etc. So I need to see the output

```
10
18
..
..
etc
```

I have no problem to do the same task if I have a one single static file and to use rdd operation.

Answer (score 1):

If someone interested, this is what I did.

```
my_DStream = ssc.textFileStream(monitor_Dir)
DStream1 = my_DStream.flatMap(process_file) 
DStream2 = DStream1.filter(lambda x: x[0])
lines_num = DStream2.count() 
lines_num.pprint()
```

This gave the desired output as I wanted.